# How to pass an array of structs from c++ to c#?

Tags: c#, c++, windows

I have been researching this for a while but can not find a solution.

I am writing a program that is using a c++/CLI wrapper. My goal right now is to return a list of all running processes and their PID (among other information) to c#. I have a running C++ function that returns a vector of type PROCESSENTRY32, but don't have the slightest clue how to get that information to c#.

I know there is a function in c# to get all running processes, but I'm trying to do it in c++.

Any tips or pointers in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Perhaps give SWIG a go (http://swig.org/). I've never used it for C#, but it certainly makes things a whole lot easier for Java.

Comment: Specifically, the "Directors" feature of SWIG allows native code to easily call into C#.

Comment: You can compile your C++ code into an assembly and refer the assembly in your C# code. Note that accessing C++ memory from C# can result in memory leak.

Comment: create a C++ wrapper to convert your vector into .net types.  You haven't shown any code, but any basic tutorial on .net and C++ will show you how to create .net types

Answer (score 0):

First, set up an api for your c# application to access data from. Declare your API functions with `__declspec(dllexport)` just before your C++ functions return type. Using a #define for this can be handy.

In C# land, make sure you have using `System.Runtime.InteropServices;` Then, make a static method handle for your api using `[DllImport("dll_name.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]` method attribute for your method then `static extern returnType CallCPPFunction();` You'll have to write a custom data parser using this method as the returned data is simply a bunch of bytes (Meaning C# will attempt to cast the received data from C++ as the return type you specify in C#). You could make a struct in C# constructed with a byte array, and set that as the constructor parameter, however, you can make your job a lot easier by sending one or more `int*` as parameters to the C# function that hold useful data like `sizeof(object)` or significant markers in the objects data to make parsing it easier. Keep in mind the memory here is simultaneously managed by C# and C++, so if you pass an `int*` holding the `sizeof(object)` you'll still need to `delete` that pointer in C++, but make sure you don't do stuff like that when C# or C++ is still using the data. You could do some `unsafe` code in C# where C++ passes a bool* that starts as false, then C# marks it as true when it's done reading the data.

I'm not an expert in this Marshalling business, but I have successfully used this exact method of transferring data in this manner in the past. It's entirely possible there's some way to use the C++ types in C# so that this data parsing isn't necessary, or C# somehow using the .h files to do stuff, but if there is, I don't know it. Here's the tutorial that I watched to figure out the concept myself, but it's a bit long and I couldn't find another one that was the same thing I was looking for:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3jGgTHJoCY

If I'm not mistaken, the data parsing won't even be necessary if you re-create the C++ struct in C# such that the first data member defined is the same associated data member in the C# struct, second C++ member to the second in C# etc. Keep in mind the size of the data types needs to match, or the data will be offset once it hits a data member whose size in C++ and C# don't match. If your struct contains sub-types you'd need to re-create those in C# too; all the way down to the primitive type level.